# Add user to an existing Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rbac

I just joined a team where they have and existing Kubernetes Cluster running in bare metal servers.
I have ssh access to the master server and nodes and I can see the Kubernetes internal pods (etcd, kube-proxy, etc) running when I execute:

```
docker ps
```

From here how can I add a user and my laptop certificate to the Cluster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850678/how-to-create-a-user-in-a-kubernetes-cluster)

Comment: they assume that kubectl is already setup in the master and nodes which is not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cluster was created using kubeadm then it should have a kubeconfig file in the `master` at `/etc/kubernetes/admin.config`. You can use kubeconfig files in kubectl with `--kubeconfig=/path/to/my.config`
If the kubeconfig is not there the administrators probably have a reason for that and you should ask them to add you as an user and create a kubeconfig for you so you can use kubectl in your own machine.

Besides that, [there is an alpha feature of kubeadm](http://kubeadm%20alpha%20kubeconfig%20user%20--client-name=foo) enabling the configuration of new users:

> ```
>   # Output a kubeconfig file for an additional user named foo
>   kubeadm alpha kubeconfig user --client-name=foo
> ```

Comment: Thanks!, this is what I was looking for. I haven't found anything related to this in the Kubernetes documentation.    The command:                                                        
   kubectl --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf get pods -n kube-system

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify.
Here are all official information you were asking about (managing cluster users and context):

- [Configure Access to Multiple Clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)

In the section
[Append $HOME/.kube/config](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#explore-the-home-kube-directory) to your KUBECONFIG environment variable it's explained more deeply.

Here is also description about using `--kubeconfig` flag

> As described previously, the output might be from a single kubeconfig file, or it might be the result of merging several kubeconfig files.
>
> If the --kubeconfig flag is set, use only the specified file. Do not merge. Only one instance of this flag is allowed.